# Error in generating documentation in Gammu with Visual Studio

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2015, python-sphinx, gammu

Can someone help me in generating documentation from Gammu with the latest version?

What I did is:

Download source code
Generate build files using Cmake for the manuals
click on the .sln file for building the manuals in Visual Studio 2015.

I keep getting errors like this:

> ```sh
>         All packages are already installed and there is nothing to restore.
> NuGet package restore finished.
> 1>------ Build started: Project: manual-htmlhelp, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
> 1>  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/AntonHipolito/Documents/Thesis Files Armada/gammu-1.36.3/docs/manual/CMakeLists.txt
> 1>  CMake does not need to re-run because C:\Users\AntonHipolito\Documents\Thesis Files Armada\gammu docs build\CMakeFiles\generate.stamp is up-to-date.
> 1>  Generating Sphinx documentation (htmlhelp)
> 1>  Traceback (most recent call last):
> 1>    File "C:\Python34\lib\runpy.py", line 169, in _run_module_as_main
> 1>      return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,"__main__", mod_spec)
> 1>    File "C:\Python34\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
> 1>      exec(code, run_globals)
> 1>    File "C:\Python34\Scripts\sphinx-build.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
> 1>    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sphinx\__init__.py", line 51, in main
> 1>      sys.exit(build_main(argv))
> 1>    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sphinx\__init__.py", line 61, in build_main
> 1>      from sphinx import cmdline
> 1>    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sphinx\cmdline.py", line 23, in <module>
> 1>      from sphinx.application import Sphinx
> 1>    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sphinx\application.py", line 37, in <module>
> 1>      from sphinx.builders import BUILTIN_BUILDERS
> 1>    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sphinx\builders\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
> 1>      from sphinx.util import i18n, path_stabilize
> 1>    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sphinx\util\i18n.py", line 15, in <module>
> 1>      from babel.messages.pofile import read_po
> 1>    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\babel\messages\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
> 1>      from babel.messages.catalog import *
> 1>    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\babel\messages\catalog.py", line 23, in <module>
> 1>      from babel.dates import format_datetime
> 1>    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\babel\dates.py", line 28, in <module>
> 1>      from babel.util import UTC, LOCALTZ
> 1>    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\babel\util.py", line 278, in <module>
> 1>      from babel import localtime
> 1>    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\babel\localtime\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
> 1>      from babel.localtime._win32 import _get_localzone
> 1>    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\babel\localtime\_win32.py", line 18, in <module>
> 1>      tz_names = get_global('windows_zone_mapping')
> 1>    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\babel\core.py", line 58, in get_global
> 1>      _global_data = pickle.load(fileobj)
> 1>  TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(170,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1.
> ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
> ```

Comment: It's perhaps this bug: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/1976